# "Signing Key Required" - Is it possible to create iOS apps using DreamWeaver CS6 Extended / PhoneGap on Windows?

Tags: ios, windows, cordova, certificate, dreamweaver

I don't have a mac, but have just signed up for the iOS developer program as I understood it is possible to create iOS native apps using DreamWeaver CS6 and PhoneGap on Windows.

The problem when I try to use the PhoneGap Build Service in DreamWeaver is that it says iOS "Signing Key Required".

I have found this page - http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/phonegap-mobile-app-pt7.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader - which outlines how to obtain the certificate, etc., but it requires a Mac.

I can get my hands on a Mac for a few hours, so should be able to complete that process. But, after that, how do I get rid of the "Signing Key Required" message on my Windows machine - or will that message disappear as my online Apple iOS developer profile is updated?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. See the comment here - http://www.phonegap.com/2012/04/24/adobe-dreamweaver-cs6-supports-phonegap-build/ - by JustMe.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using Dreamweaver CS5.5 or CS6 you dont't need to have mac book to create an ios app.
But if you are planning to deploy your app in appstore you need an ios device or virtual machine (mac book, imac) to do that.

Answer (score 0):

IMO you won't be able to package the app on your windows machine. But you definitely can still package it using the online service called PhoneGap Build that does the packaging part for you. For that, you won't need a mac.